# Android, how to make that google mapview exist in only a portion of the screen

Tags: android, layout, textview, android-mapview

I'm trying to use a mapview object in my app, but I need to simultaneously display additional information. I'd like to have have some textviews under the map, but I can't seem to display the mapview without it expanding to the entire screen. I've tried both linearlayout and relativelayout.

I'm attaching an image that shows how the bottom TextView is draw on top of the "google" logo, and hides part of it. I want (should?) have this displayed (give credit where credit is due). MY only alternative that I can figure out is to put all my text at the top of the map, which I have reasons for not wanting to do.

Any help and/or tricks would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Sid

Here is my code

```
import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class maptest extends MapActivity {
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(com.isti.sms.R.layout.mapviewtest);
        MapView mv = (MapView)this.findViewById(com.isti.sms.R.id.mapview);

        mv.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    }
    @Override
    protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }
}
```

And the xml is

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/topLayout"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <com.google.android.maps.MapView
        android:id="@+id/mapview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/LabelArea"
        android:apiKey="my long key"
        android:clickable="true" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/LabelArea"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/eventinfo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:padding="5dip"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textColor="#0000FF" >
    </TextView>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/hrlegendtx"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:text="1 Hr"
        android:textColor="#0000FF" />
</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image: image showing bottom of map obscured]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use LinearLayout and layout_weight property:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <com.google.android.maps.MapView
        android:id="@+id/mapview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:apiKey="my long key"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:clickable="true" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/hrlegendtx"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:text="1 Hr"
        android:textColor="#0000FF" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work. The TextView is not seen. I'm not sure if it is under the MapView, or off the bottom of the screen. But All I get is the map and no TextView with this layout. (Android 2.3, CyanogenMod7, btw)

Comment: oops, it does work if I replace the layout_height = 0dp of the TextView with something non-zero. I didn't notice that the first time through. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @shellman i don't know why behaviour appears, but you can use relative layout: textview - bottom; under map view.